# using jquery's each() to add click events to imgs

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery's each() to add click events to a set of imgs , this works fine but i want each img to have a different effect on click it .

```
$('#worksfoot img').each( function() {

    $(this).click( function() {



        $('#entrycontainer').animate({
        marginLeft:  

        },500); })



})
```

I would like for the first img to set marginLeft as 0 , then increment it 100 for each of the others .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the following solution:

```
$('#worksfoot img').each( function(index) {
    $(this).click( function() {
        $('#entrycontainer').animate({
            marginLeft: 100*index
        },500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work , though it looks like it should.  When I add alert(index) to the click event I don't get a dialogue box .

Comment: also it freezes the buttons that also animate #entrycontainer

Answer (score 1):

```
('#worksfoot img').each( function(index, elem) {
    elem.click( function() {
        $('#entrycontainer').animate({
        marginLeft:  100*index
        },500); })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use multiple id's for different elements.
To make it work fine and always try using class instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#worksfoot img').each( function(index) {

    $(this).click( function() {

        $('#entrycontainer').animate({
             marginLeft: index * 100 

        },500); })



})
```